# Find but skip strings and comments?

Tags: visual-studio

One thing that constantly annoys me about VS is that when I do a `Find` or `Find all`, it looks in comments, strings, and other places. When I'm trying to find a particular bit of code, like `and rent`, it finds it all over. Is there a way to limit searches just to code?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a specific setting to ignore comments, but you could do a regex find. For example, assuming you want to find "text", you could use this:

```
^(?!\s*?//).*?text
```

Caveats:

- Assumes comments start with `//` as first non-whitespace characters. E.g. C# comment types
- Doesn't work for comments at the end of code lines (only comments on their own lines)
- Doesn't work with block comments, for example `/* comment */`

So overall it isn't perfect by any means, but depending how many hits you are getting, it might help to cut them down which can be useful if you have a lot of false positives in one-liner comments

Answer (score 0):

The 'Find All References' function may suit you : it ignores all commented-out code and text in strings. CTRL+K, R is the keyboard shortcut.

(Note that it's designed for going from a specific instance of a search string to all other instances. so if you haven't already found an instance of what you're searching for, you would have to (temporarily) type one in to the editor window, then search. Also it's not available for all languages : I know it works fine for C#, though.)